# How to assign numbers 1-26 to letters a-z and then sum the output of a string in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm tasked with writing a Haskell program that'll prompt the user to input a string, and then the program will assign a number to each letter(e.g. a = 1, d = 4, y = 25, z = 26) and then it will sum the total from the string. Example "Hi" would equal 8 + 9 or 17. I've got something to do the first part but only if its in all caps, but I still can't figure out how to get the output list summed.

```
import Data.Char

toOrder :: [Char] -> [Int]
toOrder str = map ((\x -> x - 64) . ord) str
```

Ideas?

Comment: First, There’s a `sum` function in Haskell. Second, to handle different case you can transform the input so that the case is uniform (all caps or all lowercase), also using standard functions: `map` to apply a function to every element of a list, and toLower/toUpper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toUpper` to regularize the characters, and `sum` to sum the list of `Int`s:

```hs
import Data.Char (ord, toUpper)

main = print $ score "Hi" -- 17

score :: String -> Int
score = sum . map (subtract 64 . ord . toUpper)
```